# Animate UIView to go up off screen then up off screen from bottom endlessly

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640685/how-to-animate-a-uiview-going-off-the-screen-to-the-right-and-then-reappearing) one. However, I want an updated version for swift, and I want it to go endlessly. Here is my animation now:

```
bubble.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 75, y: -120)

UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 2.5,
    animations: {
        self.bubble.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.view.frame.height * -1.3)
    }
)
```

After the bubble goes off screen, I want it to go back on from the bottom and go up off screen again and again endlessly.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622451-animate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the option from the UIViewAnimationOptions set:

```
UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat
```

Should look like this with your code:

```
bubble.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 75, y: -120)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat], animations: {
               self.bubble.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.view.frame.height * -1.3)
               })
```

Comment: Which version of swift is this for? I am using swift 4 and this does not work.

Comment: try `options: [.Repeat]`

Comment: @Slaknation if its not working, that's meant you do something wrong